# Getting a particular key value for all object in JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

This is my JSON:

```
{
"Frames":
[
{"Image":"1.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"2.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"3.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"4.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"5.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"6.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"7.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"8.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"9.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"10.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"11.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"12.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"13.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"14.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"15.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"16.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"17.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"18.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"19.png", "Time":"0.04"},
{"Image":"20.png", "Time":"0.04"}
]
}
```

I want to save each value (here in total 20) of `Image` key in one `NSMutableArray` name `imageNamesArray` and each value of `Time` key in another `NSMutableArray` name `durationArray`.

I try with `[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Frames.Image"]` like below:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"animation" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *detailsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.imageNamesArray addObject:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Frames.Image"]];
[self.durationArray addObject:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Frames.Time"]];

NSLog(@"imageNamesArray %@", [imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"durationArray %@", durationArray);
```

But, It save all the `Image` key value in first row of `imageNamesArray` (What I mean is `[imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:0]`). And same for `durationArray`. How suppose I do it?
Thanks a lot in advance.

**OUT PUT WILL BE**

```
imageNamesArray = 1.png, 2.png...........20.PNG
durationArray = 0.04, 0.04...............0.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use first frames object as array and loop inside it.

```
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"animation" ofType:@"json"];
        NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //this is your loop array
        NSArrray *objArray=[dictionary objectForKey:@"Frames"];

        NSMutableDictionary *detailsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in objArray) {
            [self.imageNamesArray addObject:dic[@"Image"]]; 
            [self.durationArray addObject:dic[@"Time"]]; 
       }

        NSLog(@"imageNamesArray %@", [imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"durationArray %@", durationArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. It's working. By the way the loop is showing an error. I fixed it like this:

for (NSDictionary *dic in objArray)
    {
        [self.imageNamesArray addObject:dic[@"Image"]];
        [self.durationArray addObject:dic[@"Time"]];
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the Each `NSDictionary` in the Frames Array and can add object to corresponding Array.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dictionary[@"Frames"]) {
    [_imageNamesArray addObject:dict[@"Image"]];
    [_durationArray addObject:dict[@"Time"]];
}
NSLog(@"imageNamesArray %@--%ld", _imageNamesArray, _imageNamesArray.count);
NSLog(@"durationArray %@--%ld", _durationArray, _durationArray.count);
```